# Is there a way to see the samples used by Ableton's Impulse instrument?

Tags: ableton

I'm running Ableton Live 8, and I've got a few Live Packs that have given me some nice presets for Ableton's Impulse drum machine plugin.  However, I prefer their Drum Rack feature (due to the easy method of effecting individual drum suonds) and would like to use the same sounds in a Drum Rack instead of in Impulse.  Impulse slots just point to samples, and so in theory if I knew where the samples are, I could load them up into Drum Racks by hand.  But I haven't found a way to do this.

Given a particular Impulse preset in Ableton Live, is there any way to list or find the samples that are used within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover the mouse over the sample's slot in Impulse, the status bar at the bottom of the screen will show the path to the sample.

Additionally, the hot-swap button for that slot (the button in the lower-right) will open the Ableton Browser and highlight that sample in the Library.

Comment: Thanks to Tone Deft and Poster on ableton.com for showing me this :)